# Prove that (the vectors) {u-2v+w, 2u+v+3w, u+8v+3w) is linearly dependent for any vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

How could I do that? My initial think was to make it all (every coordinate times a scalar, c1, c2, c3) equal to $0$. Is that right?
I'm studying for my linear algebra test and don't know exactly how to this, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I am asuming $\{v,u,w\}$ is a basis for your vector space. Write the vectors as $$v_1=(1,-2,1)\\v_2=(2,1,3)\\v_3=(1,8,3)$$

Now take three arbitrary constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. We want to know if the equation $$\alpha v_1+\beta v_2+\gamma v_3=(0,0,0)$$ has a solution $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ different from $0,0,0$. You can write this as system

$$\begin{align}\alpha+2\beta+\gamma=&0\\-2\alpha+\beta+8\gamma=&0\\\alpha+3\beta+3\gamma=&0\end{align}$$

The second row plus two times the first, and the last row minus the first give $$\begin{align}\alpha+2\beta+\gamma=&0\\5\beta+10\gamma=&0\\ \beta+2\gamma=&0\end{align}$$

so the system reduces to $$\begin{align}\alpha+2\beta+\gamma=&0\\ \beta+2\gamma=&0\end{align}$$

which has a non-zero solution. Thus the set is linearly dependent.

Comment: Nice approach. (+1).

Answer (score 1):

This is related to **Peter Tamaroff**'s solution, in which one reverses the usual roles of the numbers and vectors, in a sense making the numbers the "vector components" and the vectors    **u**   ,    **v**  ,  and  **w**  the "unknown coefficients".  So saying, we find that the matrix of "vectors"

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&2&1\\-2&1&8\\1&3&3\end{array}\right] $$

is singular (its determinant is zero).  Thus, the set   {  **u** - 2 **v** + **w**   ,  2 **u** + **v** + 3 **w**  ,   **u** + 8 **v** + 3 **w** } is linearly dependent for all choices of  **u**   ,    **v**  ,  and  **w**  .  [Indeed, we find that

3 (**u** - 2 **v** + **w**)  +  [-2] (2 **u** + **v** + 3 **w**)  +   (**u** + 8 **v** + 3 **w**)  =  0  . ]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $3,-2,1{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$